# Twilio send multiple messages to sing number - python

Tags: python, twilio, sms

I can't send multiple reply to single number.

It got 1 reply together 2 messages.

"**How are you?I'm here to help you.**"

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/bot', methods=['POST'])
def bot():
    incoming_msg = request.values.get('Body', '').lower()
    resp = MessagingResponse()
    msg = resp.message()
    responded = False
    if 'Hi' in incoming_msg:
        response = "How are you?"
        msg.body(response)
        
        response2 = "I'm here to help you."
        msg.body(response2)

        responded = True

    if not responded:
        msg.body('BYE')

    return str(resp)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

Twilio messages with multiple `<Body>` nouns will be concatenated, see the [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/twiml/message#nouns):

> The text of the message you want to send. Must be less than 1600 characters. If more than one `<Body>` element is used in a single `<Message>` the contents of the two will be concatenated together into a single Body value.

I.e. with `MessagingResponse` you can only send a *single* reply. If you really want to send *multiple* replies you'll need to create the first one with [`client.messages.create(...)`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/quickstart/python?code-sample=code-send-an-sms-using-twilio&code-language=Python&code-sdk-version=6.x#send-an-outbound-sms-with-python) and return the second one via your webhook.